# Cumulative Flow Diagramas (CFD) in Azure DevOps for Tasks

Tags: azure-devops, scrum, azure-boards

Is there any possibility to get a CFD diagram in Azure DevOps for tasks?

If you enter in backlog -> Analytics I can get this diagram but for the entire backlog for User stories or backlog item, but I want to do the same for tasks (We divide the User stories in tasks and we want to know how many team is each task in each column (this columns are in the sprints view, and aren't the same for the backlog view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a Flow Metrics perspective it doesn't make a lot of sense to track tasks, as these are not value-carrying-items. Generally you apply CFD, Cycle time etc on the level of items that deliver value to an end-user or customer.

The CFD widget in Azure DevOps is therefore tied to a Backlog level that's higher than the Sprint level.

You can create a similarly looking CFD from a work item query on your team dashboard:

- Create a work item query for all task work items in the sprint
- Save it as a shared query
- Go to the dashboard and add a "Workitem Chart" widget
- Configure it with the query you created
- Pick Stacked Area
- Group by State

That will result in a simple CFD.

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing, I did it but the problem is the states that appear are the states related with the User Stories and not with the tasks (for example, we don't have environments columns in User stories but we have them for tasks, we can have a task in staging or development, but US only pass to production when all their tasks are in production).

btw I agree with you about these usually doesn't make sense, but in this case, it's a kind of project without US, there are only integrations technical tasks from a big epics, and we would like to track how many time spends each task in each env

Comment: The only workaround is to use a custom work item type at the Product Backlog level. But that takes away a bunch of Sprint management features.